# How to calculate the hour,min between two date time?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two date's

```
$date1 = "2014-02-11 04:04:26 AM"
$date2 = "2014-02-11 05:36:56 AM"
```

I want to calculate the difference and display it as follows

`1 hour 32 minutes`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make use of `DateTime::diff` of the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) Class

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2014-02-11 04:04:26 AM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-02-11 05:36:56 AM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%h')." Hours ".$interval->format('%i')." Minutes";
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
1 Hours 32 Minutes
```

Comment: One simple question,How can I convert 1 hours 32 minutes to hour.I mean I want to the result in hour.Any Idea?

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you want as an expected output ?

Comment: You mean like 1 Hours 30 Minutes -> 1.5 Hours? Just divide the minute with 60.

Comment: I presume that if $datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-03-11 05:36:56 AM'); the answer will be the same...

Comment: If the difference between the dates is more than 24 hours, then the result is wrong. This answer will give hours only between 0 and 23.

Answer (score 15):

Simply convert both dates to timestamp if dont want to do it in complex way...
Something like this

```
$dateDiff = intval((strtotime($date1)-strtotime($date2))/60);

$hours = intval($dateDiff/60);
$minutes = $dateDiff%60;
```

and there you go...

Thank you...

Comment: Your answer is correct but you have to subtract date1 from date1.

Comment: How to find $seconds also?

Comment: to get days you have to do this '$days = intval($duree/(60*24));
        $hours = intval($duree/60)%24;
        $minutes = $duree%60;
        return "$days J $hours H $minutes m";'