# PHP How to calculate the hour and minutes between two dates?

Tags: php, date, strtotime, between

This php script gives differences days and hour between two dates. But i can't calculate remaining minutes

```
  <?php
    $datestr="2011-09-23 19:10:18";
    $date=strtotime($datestr);
    
    $diff=$date-time();//time returns current time in seconds
    $days=floor($diff/(60*60*24));//seconds/minute*minutes/hour*hours/day)
    $hours=round(($diff-$days*60*60*24)/(60*60));
    
    echo "$days days $hours hours remain<br />";
    ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the hour,min between two date time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692911/how-to-calculate-the-hour-min-between-two-date-time)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)